# Does Word2Vec maintain the sequential information of the input text?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, word2vec

I ask because i'd like to use it to process the text input that I will be using for my LSTM.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, it is "word" to vector. What it does is, to represent words in their vector form. It's more like placing similar words grouped together in the space.

Like, 'cat' and 'kitten' represent similar meaning, so they will be closer to each other, i.e, their vector representation will be similar. Whereas, vector representation of 'man' will be quite far apart when placed in the same space.

[Here](http://anupkumargupta.me/blog/Word2Vec/) is a beautiful blog post which talk about word2vec in detail.